# Been stuck trying to figure out issue for an hour now

Tags: python, if-statement, input

This code is supposed to give an error message, "Error please try again!" If the colors entered are not red, blue, or yellow. It's giving me the error message while also giving me the correct input and I cannot figure out why.

```
ColorOne = input('Enter the first primary color please ')
ColorTwo = input('Enter the second primary color please ')
if ColorOne != ('red' or 'blue' or 'yellow'):
        print('Error please try again!')
if ColorTwo != ('red' or 'blue' or 'yellow'):
        print('Error please try again!')
if ColorOne == ('red') and ColorTwo == ('blue'):
        print('Purple')
if ColorOne == ('red') and ColorTwo == ('yellow'):
        print('Orange')
if ColorOne == ('blue') and ColorTwo == ('yellow'):
        print('Green')
if ColorTwo == ('red') and ColorOne == ('blue'):
        print('Purple')
if ColorTwo == ('red') and ColorOne == ('yellow'):
        print('Orange')
if ColorTwo == ('blue') and ColorOne == ('yellow'):
        print('Green')
```

Comment: @6ixxo, the question does not give any insight into the issue, please edit it.

Comment: @LeiYang The `(value)` part works fine here, the literal for a tuple with a single element is `(value,)`. Instead the problem is the use of `or`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
ColorOne = input('Enter the first primary color please ')
ColorTwo = input('Enter the second primary color please ')
if ColorOne not in ['red','blue','yellow']:
        print('Error please try again!')
if ColorTwo not in ['red','blue','yellow']:
        print('Error please try again!')
if ColorOne == ('red') and ColorTwo == ('blue'):
        print('Purple')
if ColorOne == ('red') and ColorTwo == ('yellow'):
        print('Orange')
if ColorOne == ('blue') and ColorTwo == ('yellow'):
        print('Green')
if ColorTwo == ('red') and ColorOne == ('blue'):
        print('Purple')
if ColorTwo == ('red') and ColorOne == ('yellow'):
        print('Orange')
if ColorTwo == ('blue') and ColorOne == ('yellow'):
        print('Green')
```

The problem with your code is with the logic, in real world (spoken language) you would say if the color is NOT red or blue or yellow then do something, but in programming logic this doesn't work like that. the != (red or blue or yellow) is equal to if the color is not red and not blue and not yellow then do something. And that's using de morgan laws.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

```
ColorTwo = input('Enter the second primary color please ')
if ColorOne not in ('red', 'blue', 'yellow'):
        print('Error please try again!')
if ColorTwo not in ('red', 'blue', 'yellow'):
        print('Error please try again!')
if ColorOne == ('red') and ColorTwo == ('blue'):
        print('Purple')
if ColorOne == ('red') and ColorTwo == ('yellow'):
        print('Orange')
if ColorOne == ('blue') and ColorTwo == ('yellow'):
        print('Green')
if ColorTwo == ('red') and ColorOne == ('blue'):
        print('Purple')
if ColorTwo == ('red') and ColorOne == ('yellow'):
        print('Orange')
if ColorTwo == ('blue') and ColorOne == ('yellow'):
        print('Green')
```

You'll need to check like this

```
if ColorTwo not in ('red', 'blue', 'yellow'):
```

Comment: This code only fixes the case for the second color, and ignores the first.

Comment: I'm assuming that the change is now pretty obvious to make but thanks @subspring, I've edited it now.

Comment: Great, thanks for fixing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code `ColorOne != ('red' or 'blue' or 'yellow'):`. It is not the correct way to check if a variable is one of those values. You should change to `ColorOne not in ('red', 'blue', 'yellow'):`

Regardless, I did some improvements.

```py
ColorOne = input('Enter the first primary color please ')
ColorTwo = input('Enter the second primary color please ')
    
Colors = ('red','blue','yellow')

combination = set((ColorOne.strip().lower(), ColorTwo.strip().lower()))

if not combination.issubset(Colors):
    print('Error please try again!')
elif combination == {'blue','red'}:
    print('Purple')
elif combination == {'red','yellow'}:
    print('Orange')
elif combination == {'blue','yellow'}:
    print('Green')
```